# Ingress portal disappeared

Tags: ingress

A few portals in my area have disappeared.  I've reset the app, and checked on my husbands game.  They are definitely gone. Why?

Answer (score 13):

Portals can be removed by Niantic if they are reported by some players. [Some possible causes](https://support.google.com/ingress/answer/3033734?hl=en):

- It doesn't exist
- It doesn't meet the criteria, which can be read more on [this page](https://support.google.com/ingress/answer/3066197?hl=en&ref_topic=2799270)
- It is dangerous, inaccessible or on private property

Comment: Niantic, also known as Google Corporation? *checks sources* Indeed, the "startup" inside the megacorp.

Comment: So, what if it doesn't meet any of those criteria and is consistent with other portals in the area. Is there a contesting process?

Answer (score 4):

The have probably been reported as invalid portals by other agents. These reports must have been made between a few weeks and a few months ago because it usually takes so long for an invalid portal report to be accepted.